How in Aharonov–Bohm effect electron is confined to the region?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharonov%E2%80%93Bohm_effect

electrically charged particle is affected by an electromagnetic potential $( φ , A )$, despite being confined to a region in which both the magnetic field $B$ and electric field $E$ are zero.

Published in 1959.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron

The wave-like nature of light is displayed, for example, when a beam of light is passed through parallel slits thereby creating interference patterns. In 1927, George Paget Thomson and Alexander Reid discovered the interference effect was produced when a beam of electrons

In 1927 it was already known that an electron is a wave. So how in 1959 one draws lines on a diagram (picture on wiki page about the effect) and by that claim electron is confined? In similarity with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment an electron propagate in all directions forward from the slit as wave, not just as a thin line.
